# How would I set a variable to a boolean?

Tags: ruby

Instead of `gets.chomp`, is there anything I can use to turn their response into a boolean?

```
puts "Do you like pizza? (yes or no)"
pizza = gets.chomp    
if pizza == "yes"
  pizza = true
else
  pizza = false
end
```

I tried `gets.to_b` and `gets.bool`, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Or shorter, `pizza = gets.chomp == 'yes'`. But yes, you have to do a variant of this. Ruby has no idea that `"yes"` should mean `true`

Comment: BTW, do you know what `chomp` is doing there? Or you just copied it from somewhere?

Comment: Thanks that worked! From my understanding chomp removes a line break that gets adds. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is doing! Keep up the learning :)

Comment: Just out of interest why would you set a variable to a boolean? thanks

Comment: Part of the course. They wanted us to convert variables to a integer, float, string and boolean. Boolean was the one I couldn't figure out for the life of me.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use `get[0]` what returns the first character and allows you to accept *y* or *yes*:

```
puts 'Do you like pizza? (yes or no)'
pizza = gets[0] == 'y'
```

Or you can define a `to_b` method on `String` yourself:

```
class String
  def to_b
    # might want to add even more values to the list
    %w( y yes true 1 ).include?(self.chomp.downcase) 
  end
end

'yes'.to_b
#=> true
'no'.to_b
#=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
puts "Do you like pizza? [yes/no]:"
pizza = gets.chomp    
case pizza
  when 'y','Y','yes'
    pizza = true
  when 'n', 'N','no' 
    pizza = false
end
puts pizza
```